# Constraint Layout Getting a default top margin for imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create a layout using constraint layout, with an ImageView on top, a button in the ImageView, a TextView below it and then another TextView below it. Following is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_image1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/news_title1"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/news_share_button_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/share_button_big"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/news_image1"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/news_image1"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_title1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:lines="3"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/news_image1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/news_read_more1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/news_cell0_textview_margin"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:typeface="monospace" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_read_more1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/news_title1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:textColor="@color/read_more_text_color"
                android:text="@string/news_read_more"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/news_cell0_textview_margin"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Everything is correct except for a small margin on top of the first ImageView. Whatever I do I cannot get rid of that margin. See the image below.

[image]

Please note the margin between the top of the ImageView and the card, that is what is troubling me.

Comment: Are you sure the image is not having that margin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `news_image`, `news_title1`, and `news_read_more1` views form a chain. Apparently, though I cannot find documentation on this, all views in a vertical chain will share vertical margins. In other words, applying a `layout_marginTop` or `layout_marginBottom` attribute to one of those three views will wind up applying it to **all three of them**.

You will have to re-allocate your margins, keeping this in mind.

### Edit

Looks like the behavior is a little more sophisticated than I thought. First of all, it looks like it only applies to views with the `spread` "chain style" (which is the default). Second, it looks like top margin is applied to the view it is specified on as well as all views *above* that one in the chain, while bottom margin is applied to the view it is specified on as well as all views *below* that one in the chain. Finally, it appears that margins are cumulative (so if you had 10dp top margin on your bottom view and 20dp top margin on your middle view, the final result would be 30dp on your top view, 30dp on your middle view, and 10dp on your bottom view).

As for how to solve this problem in your specific case? You should be able to use left/right margins without issue. And then probably you should use bottom margin on your top view to space the three views out.

### Edit #2

Muthukrishnan's answer made me realize that you could solve this problem by simply removing the chain from your views. If you delete the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/news_title1"` constraint from your ImageView, that will break the chain and now the vertical margins aren't shared.

Comment: Great!!! That indeed was a starter, I sacrificed all the vertical margins and I got the top margin of Image right. Any proper solution to this issue?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT I've updated my answer with some more info. Hopefully that is enough for you to be able to take it from here. Good luck.

Comment: Muthukrishnan's answer was good enough in solving my problem, except one place. Breaking the chain by removing that constraint removes even the bottom margin from the bottom TextView. Adding bottom margin for the first view was a better solution. It solved my problem, however in other cases I have scenarios where I need to play with margins little more. So checking into other possible methods to break the chain. Thanks for the great starter. :)

Comment: thanks to the great starter, I managed to solve the issue. I just had to change the default chain style (which is `spread` as you mentioned) to `spread_inside`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the great starter by Ben P, I managed to figure out a solution. There are three(plus one weighed) chaining styles available in ConstraintLayout. According to [this great tutorial](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb) the chaining styles are explained as:

1. **Spread**: The views are evenly distributed. E.g.
   `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle=”spread” 
   app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle=”spread”`
2. **Spread inside**: The first and last view are affixed to the constraints on each end of the chain and the rest are evenly distributed. E.g.
   `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle=”spread_inside” 
   app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle=”spread_inside”`
3. **Packed**: The views are packed together (after margins are accounted for). You can then adjust the whole chain’s bias (left/right or up/down) by changing the chain’s head view bias. E.g.
   `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle=”packed” 
   app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle=”packed”`
4. **Weighted**: When the chain is set to either spread or spread inside, you can fill the remaining space by setting one or more views to “match constraints” (0dp). By default, the space is evenly distributed between each view that's set to "match constraints," but you can assign a weight of importance to each view using `thelayout_constraintHorizontal_weight` and `layout_constraintVertical_weight attributes`. If you're familiar with `layout_weight` in a linear layout, this works the same way. So the view with the highest weight value gets the most amount of space; views that have the same weight get the same amount of space.

`spread` is the default chaining style. I changed it to `spread_inside` so that the first and last views are affixed to the constraints on each end of the chain(hence obeying the margins provided). The xml now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_image1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/news_title1"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/news_share_button_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/share_button_big"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/news_image1"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/news_image1"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_title1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:lines="3"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/news_image1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/news_read_more1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/news_cell0_textview_margin"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:typeface="monospace" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_read_more1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/news_title1"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:textColor="@color/read_more_text_color"
                android:text="@string/news_read_more"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/news_cell0_textview_margin"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I remove `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` in your layout it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_image1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/news_share_button_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/news_image1"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/news_image1"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
            <AliasTextView
                android:id="@+id/news_title1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:lines="3"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/news_image1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/news_cell0_textview_margin"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:typeface="monospace" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_read_more1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/news_title1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:textColor="@color/read_more_text_color"
                android:text="@string/news_read_more"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/news_cell0_textview_margin"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: It didn't help. Plus I need the image to be centerCrop, don't want it to scale.

Comment: app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9" is this mandatory for you..?

Comment: Yes, that is the main reason I opted to use ConstraintLayout.

Comment: That actually solved the problem in question, but now the bottom margin of the bottom most TextView also got removed.

Comment: removed means, you are not able to see that text.?

Comment: No, the text is viewable, but there was a 10dp margin, which no longer is there, which makes the UI doesn't look so good.

Comment: You already have **android:layout_margin="@dimen/news_cell0_textview_margin"** it should work check news_cell0_textview_margin is 10dp or not

Comment: That is there. But I think the problem is according to Ben P's answer below when the chain is broken, it even negates the bottom margin. I figured out the solution however. I just had to change the default chain style.

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way. :)

Comment: You're Welcome Friend :)